# How to order query result by multipart X.Y[.Z] "version" numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this data:

```
nov_id
2.1.1 
2.1.10
2.1.11
2.1.12
2.1.13
2.1.14
2.1.2 
2.1.3 
2.1.4 
2.1.5 
2.1.6 
2.1.7 
2.1.8 
2.1.9 
2.2   
2.3   
2.4   
2.5   
2.6
```

I need to order my results so my result expected is this:

```
nov_id
2.1.1 
2.1.2 
2.1.3 
2.1.4 
2.1.5 
2.1.6 
2.1.7 
2.1.8 
2.1.9 
2.1.10
2.1.11
2.1.12
2.1.13
2.1.14
2.2   
2.3   
2.4   
2.5   
2.6
```

This is one of my tries:

```
Select nov_id 
From dbo.NS_tbl_sc_novedad
Order by Convert(int,Left(Ltrim(Rtrim(replace(nov_id,'.','')))+'0000',4));
```

I tried to paste some zero's and order by that but, obviously I don't get it yet.

Comment: Your value 2.1.1 is not numeric and hence cannot be converted to float in order to sort the column.

Comment: what is the type of your column?

Comment: the data type is nvarchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with any string that has 2 or 3 parts with any number of digits in the number, e.g 1546.345.245 and 999.34

```
select
  nov_id
from data
cross apply (
  select charindex('.', nov_id) as pos
) as c1
cross apply (
   select charindex('.', nov_id, c1.pos+1) as pos
) as c2
order by
  convert(int, left(nov_id, c1.pos-1)),
  convert(int, substring(nov_id, c1.pos+1, isnull(nullif(c2.pos, 0), 100)-c1.pos-1)),
  convert(int, case c2.pos when 0 then 0 else substring(nov_id, c2.pos+1, 100) end)
```

Looks little messy, though :)

Answer (score 2):

For your particular data, this will work:

```
order by left(mov_id, 3),
         len(mov_id),
         mov_id
```

The idea is to order by the length, because the smaller numbers at the end have a shorter length -- given how the values are stored.

This can be revised to be more general, depending on what your data really looks like.

Comment: It also won't work when the first part goes to double digits (ex 10.1.1)

Comment: This explicitly does work on the sample data.  This is not advertised to work on every possible combination of data.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT nov_id
FROM @example
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN PARSENAME(nov_id, 3) IS NULL THEN 
    CAST(PARSENAME(nov_id, 2) AS INTEGER)*10000
    +CAST(PARSENAME(nov_id, 1) AS INTEGER)*100
  ELSE 
    CAST(PARSENAME(nov_id, 3) AS INTEGER)*10000
    +CAST(PARSENAME(nov_id, 2) AS INTEGER)*100
    +CAST(PARSENAME(nov_id, 1) AS INTEGER)
  END
```

Borrowing from Nathan Bedford's 'hijacking' the PARSENAME function in [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

It'll work for numbers up to 99.99.99. To support more digits you'd need to increase the multiples in the CASE statement.

Comment: Please try to increase to 4 dots :) something like 1.20.3.2.1

Comment: This technique won't do that!

Answer (score 0):

This is my (possibly over engineered solution)...but it works

```
    declare @temp table (value varchar(20),orderby int)

insert into @temp (value)
Values( '2.1.1'),
('2.1.10'),
('2.1.11'),
('2.1.12'),
('2.1.13'),
('2.1.14'),
('2.1.2'),
('2.1.3'), 
('2.1.4'),
('2.1.5'),
('2.1.6'),
('2.1.7'),
('2.1.8'),
('2.1.9'),
('2.2'),   
('2.3'),   
('2.4'),   
('2.5'),   
('2.6') 

UPdate @temp set orderby= case when len(replace(value,'.',''))=2 then replace(value,'.','')*100
                               when len(replace(value,'.',''))=3 then replace(value,'.','')*10
                               else replace(value,'.','') end
SELECT value FROM @temp
order by orderby ASC
```

The above gives the result set

```
2.1.1
2.1.10
2.1.11
2.1.12
2.1.13
2.1.14
2.1.2
2.1.3
2.1.4
2.1.5
2.1.6
2.1.7
2.1.8
2.1.9
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
2.6
```